# Ajax call to Mailchimp API 3.0 returns HTTP 501

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to simply subscribe a mail address with the name to a MailChimp list. 
I thought this should be very easy but I can't manage to post the mail address there.

You can find the full code here (key=authkey):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#blogsignup').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url : "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/247e2f0702/members/",
            dataType : "json",
            headers: { "Content-Type":"application/json", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "key-us12" },
            type : 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data :  {
                apikey: "key", 
                email_address: $('#TBemail').val(),
                status: 'subscribed',            
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: "subscriberFirstName",
                    LNAME: "subscriberLastName"
                }
            },
            // Try to send also before
            beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                "Basic " + btoa("api:" + "key-us12")); 
            },                  
            success : function (data) {
                $('#signup').html("Thanks for signing up. We will contact you as fast as possible.");
            },
            error : function (data, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The function is triggered when clicking the submit button. 
I always get the alert "error" and it's saying

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/247e2f0702/members/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://preprod.travelgap.io' is therefore not allowed access.

The response had HTTP status code 501.

I was also trying `jsonp` as Datatype then I get a 401 error. Authkey not passed.

Comment: Need to use a proxy on your server. You don't want your api key exposed, and neither does mailchimp

Comment: First it would be nice that its working then I can implement a Proxy?

Comment: Need to get it working on your server. The API is not CORS enabled for using ajax

Comment: ok thx. Then i try with curl :)

Comment: Somebody please write an answer. stop using comments as answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This means that the client (making the AJAX call) is not permitted to directly hit the API. Your current architecture:

```
Client (any origin) ---> MailChimp API
```

What you should do, as suggested already, is use your server to proxy over the request to the remote API, so that you don't violate their CORS rule. You should add an API endpoint on your server which, when accessed by a client, makes a server-side network request to the MailChimp API.

```
Client (any origin) ---> Server (known, whitelisted origin) ---> MailChimp API
```

Also, your API key should never exist in client code. Your API key should be considered a secret available only server-side. The latter architecture ensures that this is the case.